# Run Get-ClusterGroup on remote server using Central server

Tags: powershell, automation, cluster-computing, powershell-2.0

I have a centralized server from which i can run the following PowerShell command to get the clustergroup of cluster servers.

```
Enter-pssession -computername (ip-address) -credential (domain user)
```

And it prompts me to enter password then i get the session and execute

```
get-clustergroup
```

Okay till this it is fine.

Now i wanted to make this fully automated by converting in to a PowerShell script

The following commands works well when i run it in Powershell ISE and gets me the output of `get-clustergroup`

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$user = "domain\user"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user,$password)

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName IP.Add.RE.SS -Credential $cred

get-clustergroup
```

but when i save the about script and run with PowerShell i get the following error.

> get-clustergroup: the cluster service is not running

[image: get-clustergroup: the cluster service is not running]

I want to automate the process by writing script to get `get-clustergroup` output of four cluster servers.

i am new to PowerShell scripting. how can i save the output?

Comment: Is this solution required to be in PowerShell v2? The look of your PowerShell console window suggests otherwise at least from the source server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a session to the other server, you can run the following which will run the command on the remote computer and return the output to your console:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <IPAddress> -ScriptBlock { Get-ClusterGroup } -Credential $cred
```

You can store that output into a variable if you wish for future retrieval.

Since `-ComputerName` can accept an array object, you can modify your command to include all four of your servers. Below shows how to use all of your computer names and store the output in the variable `$Output`:

```
$Output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Server1","Server2","Server3","Server4" `
         -ScriptBlock {Get-ClusterGroup} -Credential $cred
$Output
```

Your computer names could also be stored in a variable as an array. Then that variable can be used in your `-ComputerName` parameter:

```
$Computers = "Server1","Server2","Server3","Server4"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock { Get-ClusterGroup } -Credential $cred
```

See [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) for more information.